# Key-valued descriptive statistics

Tags: java, apache, statistics, apache-commons-math

I am using Apache DescriptiveStatistics to compute stats, but there is a problem. I have a bunch of entities generating values and on each iteration I would like to update the value associated with the entity.

For example I may track current temperature in 1000 different locations across the city and I would like to be able to compute some average temperature for the city:

```
for (Location location: locations) {
    double temperature = location.getCurrentTemperature();

    stats.update(location, temperature);
}

// Average: stats.getMean();
```

It there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Math does not provide the exact, key-based updating you are requesting.

However, if for each iteration you are using observations from all the locations and if the number and order of locations is maintained from iteration to iteration then `DescriptiveStatistics` might work.

Initialize the `DescriptiveStatistics` instance with a window size equal to the number of locations.  Then, after each iteration the mean from DescriptiveStatistics should be the average across all the locations.

```
// initialize stats with fixed window size
DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics(locations.size());

// add current value from each location
for (Location location : locations) {
    stats.addValue(location.getCurrentTemperature());
}

// after each loop the stats will be computed across all the locations
double average = stats.getMean();
```